# Querying DB inside SQLAlchemy Model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model that looks something like this:

```
class Guest(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String)

    current_status_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('approval_status.id'))
    current_status = db.relationship('ApprovalStatus')
```

I would like to have a method like this:

```
    def reset_status(self):
        awaiting_response = db.session.query(Approvalstatus).get(1)
        self.current_status = awaiting_response
```

Querying from within the model does not seem right to me for some reason. However, it seems that this logic belongs on the `Guest` class.

Currently, I have a guest service that looks something like this:

```
def reset_guest_approval(guest):
        awaiting_response = db.session.query(Approvalstatus).get(1)
        guest.current_status = awaiting_response
```

I want to consolidate the logic into the class if possible. What are the best practices on this?

Answer (score 1):

In my similar case, I used `object_session` for making a query inside the class function.

```
class Guest(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String)

    current_status_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('approval_status.id'))
    current_status = db.relationship('ApprovalStatus')

    def reset_status(self):
        awaiting_response = object_session(self).query(Approvalstatus).get(1)
        self.current_status = awaiting_response
```